# data not pass between fragment to dailog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an app where I send data from one fragment to a dialog fragment 
through a Bundle and pass that string with hash map and save that data to a database. When I send data from the fragment to the dialog fragment, it does not get there and I get the following error and my app crashes:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Fragment code:

```
private void mobileNumber()
{

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("mobile", edtMobileNumber.getText().toString());
    DialogFragment newFragment = new Save_contact_fragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
 //   newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"TAG");

}
```

In this code I am sending a mobile number to the dialog fragment. Dialog fragment code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TokenModel mTokenModel = ((BaseActivity)getActivity()).getTokenDetails();
    if (mTokenModel != null) {
        mAuthorizationHeader = mTokenModel.getTokenType() + " " + mTokenModel.getAccessToken();
    }


    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    data = args.getString("mobile");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_save_contact, container, false);
    initUI(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    /*Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle == null) {
        data = bundle.getString("mobile");
    }*/

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

private void initUI(View view) {

    btnsave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);
    btnCancelDialog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);


    etPromoCode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_promo_code);
    etPromoCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().length() > 0) {
                btnsave.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btnsave.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });

    // Should always be at the end
    bindClicks();
}

private void bindClicks() {
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            callAddToContactAPI();

            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //dismiss();
        }
    });

    btnCancelDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private void callAddToContactAPI() {

    if (selectedPlan == null) {
        selectedPlan = new SaveContactModel();
        //selectedPlan.setRemark(Constants.CATEGORY_MOBILE_RECHARGE);

        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    //selectedPlan.setPlanMrp(Integer.parseInt(Utils.getTextFromEditText(etPromoCode)));
    addToContactAPI(selectedPlan);
}

private void addToContactAPI(SaveContactModel saveContactModel) {

    if (!Utils.isNetworkConnected(getActivity())) {
        return;
    }
    CartClient cartClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(CartClient.class);

    HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();

    parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_ContactName,Utils.getTextFromEditText(etPromoCode));
    parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_ContactNumber,data);
    parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_ServiceID_TO_SAVE, 1);
    parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_UserBasicID,"1593");


    Call<String> cart = cartClient.addToContact(mAuthorizationHeader, parameterMap);

    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String abc = cart.request().url().toString();

    cart.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            if(response.code() == 200) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyContactActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

                Utils.showAlertDialogWithMessage(Constants.CONTACT_ADDED, getActivity());

                //  Utils.showAlertDialogWithMessage(Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE_ITEM_ADDED_TO_CART, getActivity());
            } else {
             //   Utils.showAlertDialogWithMessage(Constants.ERROR_UNABLE_TO_PROCESS_REQUEST, getActivity());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            Utils.showShortToastMessage(getActivity(), Constants.ERROR_OOPS_SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG);
        }
    });


}
```

Here is where I receive data in the dialog fragment:

```
Bundle args = this.getArguments();
data = args.getString("mobile");
```

But I get null and get an error when I pass that data string to a hash map. I do that in the following code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();

parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_ContactName,Utils.getTextFromEditText(etPromoCode));
parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_ContactNumber,data);
parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_ServiceID_TO_SAVE, 1);
parameterMap.put(Constants.ADD_UserBasicID,"1593");
```

The mobile number is not there in the bundle.

Comment: are you sure that your `Save_contact_fragment` is the `dialogue fragment`?

Comment: Yes
public class Save_contact_fragment extends DialogFragment {

Comment: ok, show the full stacktrace then

Comment: can i change any thing in Activity i get data  Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("mobile", edtMobileNumber.getText().toString());
    DialogFragment newFragment = new Save_contact_fragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

Comment: i get data here but data no read in  DialogFragment what should i do

Comment: Please read my last comment

Answer (score 0):

put this part:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
data = args.getString("mobile");
```

in `onCreateView` instead of `onCreate` and without `this.`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your passed argument in `onViewCreated` or into `onCreateView` method. If you don't receive bundle, a default string will be used if arguments are different than `null`.

```
String mobile = getArguments() != null ?  getArguments().getString("mobile", "defaultString") : "defaultString";
```

Comment: data = getArguments() != null ?  getArguments().getString("mobile", "defaultString") : "defaultString";

Comment: i got data null

Comment: Data? Who's data?

Comment: i got null in String mobile

Comment: How you instantiate dialog fragment?

Comment: how i instantiate   dialog fragment can you plz give me example

Comment: can i add anythhing in Activity